# HTML Collection - Remove Elements During While Loop

Tags: javascript

I have an HTML Collection and I am wanting to remove items 0-2 and items 19-28 when the second item in the collection is clicked. What am I missing here?

```
//Add on OnClick command to the second element of the HTML collection.
document.getElementsByClassName("esg-filterbutton")[1].addEventListener("click", myFunction);

//Remove elements 0-2 and 19-28 from the collection.
function myFunction(){
  while (i<3 && i>18 && i<29){
  .esg-filterbutton.remove();
 }
}
```

Thanks,

Jonathan

Comment: looks like you need to store the elements by class name in a variable (an array of elements) and loop thru them.  Nothing is defining `i` in your function; nothing is defining `.esg-filterbutton`, etc.

Comment: `.esg-filterbutton` is actually not valid JavaScript code. It actually looks like the selector in a CSS ruleset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have forgotten to actually reference the collection, also your loop is invalid.

This code should do what you want:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("esg-filterbutton")[1].addEventListener("click", myFunction);


var filters = document.getElementsByClassName("someClassName");
//Remove elements 0-2 and 19-28 from the collection.
function myFunction(){
 for (var i = 0;i<29; i++){
  if (i === 3) { // Skip elements 3 to 18
    i = 19;
    continue;
  }
  filters[i].remove();
 }
}
```

Comment: running the snippet shows: > Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of undefined - you may want to debug your answre

Comment: Nor the HTML or the name of the class are included in OP's answer so the snippet bit was just for the editor, removed it to avoid confusion.

Comment: @JonathanHartman Did you replace the class names to the appropriate ones?

Answer (score 1):

My answer removes the elements 0-2 and 12-14... see if that helps you

**Hint**: click on the 'filter' button and open console to see results

```js
//Add on OnClick command to the second element of the HTML collection.
document.getElementById("esg-filterbutton").addEventListener("click", myFunction);

//Remove elements 0-2 and 12-14 from the collection.
function myFunction() {
  var elementArray = document.getElementsByClassName('filter');
  var reducedElementArray = [];

  for (var index = 0; index < elementArray.length; index++) {
    if (!(index >= 0 && index <= 2) &&
      !(index > 11 && index < 15)) {
      reducedElementArray.push(elementArray[index]);
    }
  }

  for (var index = 0; index < reducedElementArray.length; index++) {
    console.log(reducedElementArray[index]);
  }
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="filter">1</li>
  <li class="filter">2</li>
  <li class="filter">3</li>
  <li class="filter">4</li>
  <li class="filter">5</li>
  <li class="filter">6</li>
  <li class="filter">7</li>
  <li class="filter">8</li>
  <li class="filter">9</li>
  <li class="filter">10</li>
  <li class="filter">11</li>
  <li class="filter">12</li>
  <li class="filter">13</li>
  <li class="filter">14</li>
</ul>
<button id="esg-filterbutton">Filter</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

To spare the problems of hard-coding the ranges in your function, you can programmatically build up the ranges with a few helper functions. I've tried a functional programming approach to this answer.

For this example we'll use ranges 0-2 and 5-6.

```
var ranges = ['0-2', '5-6'];
```

First thing is to replace `getElementsByClassName` with `querySelectorAll`. This will allow us to work with a static rather than a live nodelist.

```
var divs = document.querySelectorAll(".esg-filterbutton");
```

When you click the second item pass the ranges into `myFunction`.

```
divs[1].addEventListener("click", myFunction.bind(this, ranges));
```

`getBounds` returns the upper and lower bounds of a range.

```
function getBounds(str) {
  return str.split('-').map(Number);
}
```

`createRange` returns a single padded range using the lower and upper bounds.

```
function createRange(range) {
  var bounds = getBounds(range), out = [];
  for (var i = bounds[0]; i <= bounds[1]; i++) out.push(i);
  return out;
}
```

`combineRanges` concatenates multiple ranges together using `concat`.

```
function concat() {
  return function (p, c) {
    return p.concat(c);
  }
}

function combineRanges(arr) {
  return arr.reduce(concat());
}
```

`getArrayRange` and `formatRanges` create the ranges to be concatenated.

```
function getArrayRange(createRange) {
  return function (el) {
    return createRange(el);
  }
}

function formatRanges(ranges) {
  return ranges.map(getArrayRange(createRange));
}
```

Finally `removeElementFrom` which returns a function to be used in `myFunction`.

```
function removeElementFrom(arr) {
  return function (el) {
    arr[el].remove();
  }
}
```

Finally, `myFunction` accepts `ranges` as an argument, combines them using the above functions, then removes each element within those ranges.

```
function myFunction(ranges) {
  var arr = combineRanges(formatRanges(ranges)).forEach(removeElementFrom(divs));
}
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/twnL26yd/). Clicking on "1" removes the elements contained in the `ranges` array.

Answer (score 0):

If you consider your collection as array, use `.splice(index,howmanyElements)` method to remove list of elements. Looping may cause performance issue if you are not checking any additional details, avoid looping